# try..except in interactive Windbg Python session throws me out of the Python session

Tags: python, windbg, prompt, pykd

I'm working with PYKD, doing dump analysis. The PYKD library is used in the heap_stat script, and I'd like to use PYKD library in a more interactive way, like this:

```
Windbg prompt>!py
Input>dbgCommand("x /2 *!CStringArray*vftable*")
```

This is working fine (I know this is useless, I just want to show that it works).

However, the heap_stat script contains following piece of source code:

```py
try:
  vftable_candidate = ptrPtr(ptr) # which pointer value is present on that spot in memory?
  dprintln("DDS vftable_candidate [%08x], ptr value [%d], ptr pointer [%08x]" % (vftable_candidate, ptr, ptr))
except:
  continue
```

When I try this interactively, this seems not to work:

```
Windbg prompt>!py
Input>ptrPtr(‭48806712‬)
```

This gives following error, throwing me out of the Python session:

```
  File "<console>", line 1


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\code.py", line 243, in interact
    more = self.push(line)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\code.py", line 265, in push
    more = self.runsource(source, self.filename)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\code.py", line 79, in runsource
    self.showsyntaxerror(filename)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\code.py", line 139, in showsyntaxerror
    map(self.write, list)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\code.py", line 171, in write
    sys.stderr.write(data)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**This is ok**: there's a reason for wrapping this function call inside of a `try..except` clause, so let's now try to wrap this function inside of a `try..except` clause in the interactive Python session:

```
Windbg prompt>!py
Input>try: ptrPtr(‭48806712‬) except: continue
```

=> This gives the same error, I get thrown out of the Python session again despite of the `try..except`. Most probably this is due to the wrong indentation, but on the other hand the interactive Windbg Python session does not allow multiline, so I can't use Python indentation.

Is there a way to use `try..except` clauses in Windbg PYKD Python session?
Thanks in advance

P.s. for your understanding: this behaviour (being kicked out of the interactive session) seems to be typical for Windbg PYKD, as you can see in following command prompt Python session:

```
Windows Prompt>python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
```

As you can see, the exception is thrown, but I don't get kicked out of the Python session (watch the `>>>` prompt).

Comment: "Is there a way to use try..except clauses in Windbg PYKD Python session?" - is that really your question? It's the only question mark I could find. Will an answer to that question help you? Or would you rather like to ask a different question, which is more helpful? This could be an XY-problem, IMHO. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use copy/paste and your input string conatains unicode symbols and python can not decode it. Try to retype 'ptrPtr(‭48806712‬)'

Comment: This might actually be the problem: when I type the command character after character, everything is working fine. But when I perform copy-paste, the whole thing goes wrong.

Comment: You probably use Visual Studio as a copy/paste source? I will try to convert input to ascii with current local charset.

Comment: Don't laugh : I've been using the standard Windows calculator, which seems to add an invisible character at the beginning and at the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

> interactive Windbg Python session does not allow multiline, so I can't
>   use Python indentation.

You are wrong. You can use multiline

```
>>> try:
...    1/0
... except:
...   print 0
... 
0
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast to accept your answer: when I try your proposal, it is working fine. But when I replace `1/0` by `ptrPtr(48806712‬)`, then I get this error message: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)`.